# Nexmo Conference Call using voice api

Tags: java, vonage, conference

I have a requirement like i need to create a nexmo conference call by creating a meeting id/ conference URL(like Zoom Calls) and send them to contacts in facebook using facebook bot and get them connected in the conference call. I have worked previously used nexmo api for IVR process, could i create a conference like zoom in `nexmo` by getting url with meeting id, any example in java would help us great